# How to click on certain text or coordinates using autoit in python

Tags: google-chrome, automation, autoit

Im trying to click a certain button on my chrome web page but it never finds the button and doesn't click on it. It would be fine to either click on the text of the button or the coordinates of it.

```py
google_chrome_pid = autoit.run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", show_flag=3)
autoit.win_wait_active("New Tab", timeout=10) 
time.sleep(0.3)
autoit.opt("SendKeyDelay", 1)
autoit.send("!d" + (itemurl))
time.sleep(0.1)
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(2)
autoit.control_click("New Tab", "add to basket")
```

Here is my code so far

Answer (score 1):

Autoit works with WinApi and can only handle Windows GUI controls. It will not detect controls inside a website, as it would for example find contols in Chrome interface.
If you are handy and the website is static, then you could try and use mouse functions to click certain screen coordinates:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm